# How to include a classpath from a file?

Tags: java

I have extracted the classpath entries in a file cp.txt using the maven build-classpath command. but now I am not sure how to run the java class using the classpath entries from the cp.txt file. Any help would appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to provide a file with classpath entries. Class path entires location has to be provided as a `-cp` or `-classpath` argument to `java` or the `CLASSPATH` environmental variable.

However you can use your shell to put the content a file into an argument,

- Unix:

  ```
  java -cp "`cat cp.txt`" ...
  ```
- Windows

  ```
  set /p classpath=<cp.txt
  java -cp %classpath% ...
  ```

Comment: It is not writing the whole file contents